# python no idea what's wrong

Tags: python, file

I want write a function to achieve open a file->choose a certain column->take out the non repeated names->write the names into another file. 
I have written some code like this:

```
def method2(filename):
    name = filename + '.txt'
    content = open(name,'r')

    for line in content:
        values = line.split()
        a = values[1]

        print(a)
```

the error is:

```
>>> method2('test')
d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:2d,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    method2('test')
  File "C:/Users/Yifan/Desktop/data/Training data/Method2.py", line 10, in method2
    a = values[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

my file looks like this:

```
  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:e8,          SUTD_Guest,   57



  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:89,           SUTD_ILP2,   74



  1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:8d,           SUTD_GLAB,   74



  1405684432,        b0:c5:54:dc:dc:6c,              ai-ap1,   85
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

**test.py**

```
def read_file(filename):
    file = open(filename)
    contents = map(str.strip,file.readlines())
    file.close()
    return contents

def get_column_values(col_num,lines):
    column_values = []

    for line in lines:
        if not line:
            continue

        values = line.split()

        #col_num - 1 = index of list
        #[:-1] will chop the last char i.e. comma from the string
        column_values.append(values[col_num-1][:-1])

    return column_values

def remove_duplicates(xList):
    return list(set(xList))


def write_file(filename,lines):
    file = open(filename,"w")
    for line in lines:
        file.write("%s\n" % line)
    file.close()


def main():
    lines = read_file("input.txt")

    #Work on 1st Column i.e. 0th index
    column_values = get_column_values(1,lines)
    entries = remove_duplicates(column_values)
    write_file("output.txt",entries)

main()
```

**input.txt**

```
1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7d:e8,          SUTD_Guest,   57

1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:89,           SUTD_ILP2,   74

1405684432,        d8:c7:c8:5e:7c:8d,           SUTD_GLAB,   74

1405684432,        b0:c5:54:dc:dc:6c,              ai-ap1,   85
```

**output.txt**
    1405684432

Answer (score 3):

When you reach the second line, which looks empty, and split it, you only get an empty list in `values`. Trying to access element `1`, i.e. the second, fails, because there is no second element.

Try putting `if len(values) > 0:` in there to protect `a = line[1]`.

Comment: You could also do `if values: ...` if you are sure that all lines contain "enough" columns.

Comment: Thank you!I got the reason :p